# oracle vb.net dataset fill

Tags: .net, oracle, datagridview, dataset

What is wrong with this code? 
No error, but no results. My DataGridView_sent does not get filled.

```
Dim objConn As New System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection
Dim objCmd As New System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand
Dim dtAdapter As New System.Data.OracleClient.OracleDataAdapter

Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim strConnString, strSQL As String

strConnString = "Data Source=db;User Id=user;Password=pass;"
strSQL = "select * from table where sentdate between '" & date1 & "' and '" & date2 & "'"

 objConn.ConnectionString = strConnString
 With objCmd
     .Connection = objConn
     .CommandText = strSQL
     .CommandType = CommandType.Text
  End With
  dtAdapter.SelectCommand = objCmd

  dtAdapter.Fill(ds)
  DataGridView_sent.DataSource = ds

  dtAdapter = Nothing
  objConn.Close()
  objConn = Nothing
```

Comment: Check values(rows) in "ds", whether data is there in database or not? and also need to check that filter for query i.e. "sentdate between '" & date1 & "' and '" & date2 & "'""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably caused by incorrect representation of dates.
You should use parametrized queries and let the Oracle Provider render in the correct mode your date fields values

```
....
strSQL = "select * from table where sentdate between :date1 and :date2" 
objConn.ConnectionString = strConnString 
With objCmd 
   .Connection = objConn 
   .CommandText = strSQL 
   .CommandType = CommandType.Text 
   .Parameters.AddWithValue(":date1", Convert.ToDateTime(date1));
   .Parameters.AddWithValue(":date2", Convert.ToDateTime(date2));
End With 
dtAdapter.SelectCommand = objCmd 
.....
```

Comment: problem not in here. still the same result. with this MsgBox(ds.Tables.Count) I get '1' even there are more rows.

Comment: oh, that gave me the writte number, it means dataset is filled. so this line DataGridView_sent.DataSource = ds is not working then. How do I will datagridview with dataset? thanks

Comment: dtAdapter.Fill(ds, "Sent")
        DataGridView_sent.DataSource = ds.Tables("Sent")   So it works. Thanks :)